# Exterior derivative of a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $G$ be a Lie group with $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. If $\omega$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $k$-form, how can I define "the exterior derivative" of $\omega$??. In particular, how can I define the expression $$X(\omega(Y)),$$ where $X$, $Y$ are vector fields

Comment: Is there any context (where did you find this term? any texts you are reading?)

Comment: The term is in analogy with "usal" exterior derivative, I assumed that there is an analogy between the "usal" exterior derivative and exterior derivative of $\mathfrak{g}$-valued forms and I assumed right according to the anserw below.

Answer (score 3):

For a general vector bundle $E\to M$, in order to define exterior derivation on $E$-valued differential forms one needs a connection on $E$. The vector bundle at hand is trivial, and so, it has the trivial connection. Consequently, there is a natural exterior derivation of $\mathfrak{g}$-valued forms.

The following is one possible way to understand the picture. This way is not canonical, but very clear. Let $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued form $\omega$ can be written as $$\omega=\sum\xi_i\otimes\omega_i,$$ where every $\omega_i$ is an ordinary differential form. The exterior derivative is then given by $$d\omega=\sum\xi_i\otimes d\omega_i.$$

**Edit:** A word of clarification, thanks to the comment by Pedro. The above computation yields a well-defined result for $d\omega$, which is independent of the chosen basis. However, the basis is not canonical, and neither are the $\omega_i$'s. Hence, this approach, as easy to understand as it is, may not be the right way to think of the matter.

Comment: What do you mean by not canonical? It's not hard to check that this expression doesn't depend on the basis chosen.

Comment: @Pedro Of course this formula gives the same result for $d\omega$ for any choice of basis. What I mean is that the basis is not canonical, and so neither are the $\omega_i$'s. Altogether, I'm just not sure that this is the "right" way to think about the matter. However, it does make the computations very simple, which is also nice.

Comment: @Pedro I even added this explanation to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think is much better the first answer , considering $\mathfrak{g}$-forms as $E$-valued forms (with $E$ trivial bundle) and use the exterior derivative associated to trivial connection. Thanks